# Console error on pages with col2-left-layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, error, javascript

I am making my mobile site and our navigation is a bar at the top which when you click expands and shows the categories. However on any pages with the layout class col2-left-layout the navigation doesn't expand, i have checked the console and it say there is an error in my script.js saying  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

and it is referring to this line

```
if ($('.col-left').length) $('.col-left').masonry({itemSelector : '.block', isResizable:true, isAnimated:true});
```

I dont understand why this is happening on only pages with certain layouts, could anyone shed some light on the situation please?

Is there a way of changing the page layout depending on the screen size, for example if viewing on a mobile device the layout changes from col2_left_layout to col1_layout??

Comment: I'd imagine masonry isn't loaded correctly on that layout. If you open the console in Chrome on that page and type `$('.col-left').masonry` what does it show?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'masonry' of null, If you meant just type that into the console and click enter?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that masonry is the jQuery plugin and on this page `$` is prototype rather than jQuery at the point the code is called. Try changing it to..

```
if (jQuery('.col-left').length) jQuery('.col-left').masonry({itemSelector : '.block', isResizable:true, isAnimated:true});
```

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: If you type jQuery in the console, what do you get?

Comment: I typed in jQuery in the console and hit eneter it comes back with function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}

Comment: And `jQuery('.col-left')`?

Comment: Returns my div that is called col-left sidebar
<div class="col-left sidebar">

Comment: Where does the code appear on the page? Is it included before the col-left div?

Comment: no it loads all the HTML then it loads the javascripts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20205/discussion-between-cags-and-adam-allen).